# Write a specific output for a folder name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some codes in HTML, I'm new with it, the most of the time I'm playing the guessing game. This code

```
file = folder.createFolder([name, surname, twitter,].join(" ~ "))createFile(blob);
```

if the variables are

- name = Alex
- surname = Red
- twitter = AleRed

creates a folder named "Alex ~ Red ~ AleRed" . Now i just want that the output folder will be a folder named " Alex ~ Red ~ Twitter: Alered". So I need to write my kind of format of the output, not just the separator between the variables. Is it possible? I don't this it will be harder

Comment: Where's the html in your code?

Comment: I'm editing a file in Google Script, the file in this script is called forms.html and this is a line of that file

Comment: It would really help if you included that information in your question. Currently your question suggests you are trying to run html code to create a folder which is nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = folder.createFolder([name, surname, "Twitter: " + twitter].join(" ~ "))createFile(blob);
```